# Is it possible to get shorter labels in Highcharts pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

What I'm trying to do is make this Pie chart:

[image: Actual pie chart]

Look more like the designed pie chart:

[image: Pie chart from design]

Making the pie chart bigger will cause the labels to fall out of div instead of shorten or repositioning. In the documentation of Highchart I found that the only options I can set on the label is "style" and "items".

Comment: You can increase size by http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size / set connetors and datalabels as you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently I didn't look well. There's a difference between Label and datalabel. the options for datalabel can be found under the pie settings. There you can set the distance; right [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance)

Comment: End you can even remove connector lines to get some space.